# Limit sudo to only one directory and it's subdirectories by sudoers file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, chmod, sudo, chown

So I would like to limit Apache to only change permissions in a certain folder and all of it's sub-directories, so this is what I have in my sudoers file

```
apache ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod -R [g+ws] /var/www/sites/[a-z]+
```

But that does not appear to work. I sure I could get it to work by removing the restriction on the subfolder, but that seems dangerous as it would give a potential hacker unlimited access.

So is there a way to limit apache to only change files and folders within the "sites" folder or am I stuck giving unlimited access with chmod / chown?

Are there any big security holes using this approach?

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question -- **WHY** do you want to do what you're asking -- what problem are you trying to solve?  There's almost always a better way than letting Apache (a server that the whole world interacts with) do *anything* as root.  (See also Michael Lowman's comment below.)

Comment: Apache should already own it's directories.  Why do you need to give it sudo permissions?

Comment: I just looked at what you are trying to do, again. I think you could accomplish what you want by setting the umask in Apache's init script.  This would be infinitely better than giving Apache sudo.

Comment: I'm trying to make a control panel for SVN. When a user does "svn up" is sets incorrect permissions and owner / group. Users also upload files into the folder and the sticky bit gets lost. So things become a mess so I want a "reset permissions" button that users can use via a web interface to make things all better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to make the chmod command a shell script to be only run by root and then allow that command to be run in sudo.

Comment: You might also want to look into ensuring that the files are set correctly upon creation; check the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Seems like a much safer way to approach this

Answer (score 3):

> Ok, So apparently this does not use full regular expressions which I
>   was expecting, a regular star did the trick:
>
> ```
> apache ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod -R [go]+ws /var/www/sites/*
> ```

This is very dangerous. It will open vulnerability in your server . What happen if a user manage to run chmod -R g+w /var/www/sites/../../../../etc/shadow?