# using wildcards for paths in sudoers file

Tags: linux, wildcard, sudo

I'm trying to set up the sudoers file to allow users to chown files only under a
certain directory

for example

```
%hmis    ALL=/bin/chown eng:hmis /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/*
```

is not good because hackers can do the following:

```
sudo chown eng:hmis /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/xctrl.py /etc/important_file
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if you solve your immediate problem, someone could still type...

```
sudo chown eng:hmis /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/../../../etc/shadow
```

Or any other permutation of the above.  `sudo` isn't really the right tool for this sort of restriction.  If you really need to delegate the ability to change ownership in a specific hierarchy like this, then your best bet is probably to write a simple wrapper script in your favorite high-level scripting language that iterates over its path arguments, sanitizes them, and checks them against a list of allowed prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

We've implemented the following which seems to work

```
Cmnd_Alias EDIT =  /bin/rvi /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/*, \
                  !/bin/rvi /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/* *, \
                  !/bin/rvi /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/*..*
```

Comment: Note this also covers inserting a `/./` before the `/../` as it will be globbed by the first star.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, I hadn't thought of that. Since I only need to use the chown command for this particular command:

```
chown eng:hmis /usr/lib/bogimac/bsc/*
```

I decided to make a shell script to be run only by root and then allow that command to be run in sudo, see [Limit sudo to only one directory and it's subdirectories by sudoers file](https://serverfault.com/questions/281648/limit-sudo-to-only-one-directory-and-its-subdirectories-by-sudoers-file)

Comment: I was going to recommend this as well -- just make sure that the users don't have access to edit or delete the script.